# Create new line for each seperated element in field (database)

Tags: php, html, database

Here's my code :

```
<div id="slides" class="col-md-7" >

    <img src="'.$row['img2'].'" >

    </div>
```

In that "img2" row in the database, it's image path. But I need to detect if there's more than one image path seperated by a comma in there.

So if there's 2 images in the field (ex.: img/image1.jpg, img/image2.jpg), well the HTML would look like :

```
<div id="slides" class="col-md-7" >

    <img src="'.$row['img2(first value)'].'" >
    <img src="'.$row['img2(second value)'].'" >

    </div>
```

But if there's only 1 value, it stays like my first code part.
Anyone? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using php? Is `$row` a php object?

Comment: I would try by using implode() to put those paths in array elements and then print the img tag for each of the elements.

Comment: I think you should revisit your database design because you should normalize it. I'd recommend using `explode` on `,` for what you have at the moment.

Comment: I am using PHP, yes. Can you guys show me a sample code using the explode function please? It would help me understand more. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the explode function and then a foreach loop

```
<div id="slides" class="col-md-7" >
<?php
    $images = explode(',', $row['img2']);
    foreach($images as $image) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" >
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: _“[…] and then a foreach loop”_ – or just `implode` :-)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, just the part I needed. Everything's fine now. Thanks again!